# Refresh Google Analytics token in R

Tags: r, token, google-analytics-api

I am using the following code to retrieve Google Analytics token in R. 
It works when I get the original token, but once it expires I am not able to refresh it. I get

> Error: Refresh token not available

after `ValidateToken(token)`. What am I doing wrong?

```
#get and store token 
require("RGoogleAnalytics")
token <- Auth(client.id,client.secret)
save(token,file="./token_file")

#Get refresh token
load("token_file")
ValidateToken(token)
```

Comment: I would recommend you to use the "RGA package" instead. I had fewer problems with it when authenticating. [RGA](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/RGA/RGA.pdf)

Comment: Thanks Omar, I have been trying with RGA but I am getting 'Missing required parameter: client_id' despite the presence of the correct client id. I'll keep searching!

Comment: @JulienMassardier: can you provide a reproducible code example which causes the error?

Comment: @ArtemKlevtsov: I used authorize(client.id = "clientid", client.secret = "secret"). Anyway, all good now with Omar's code. Tks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to make a complete answer for this case.

`RGA` automatically refreshes the token, unless you specify it not to do so.

Run this lines, and use `View(ga_profiles)` to get the right ID you need. It is the ID for the View (Not the Account ID). In `ga_profiles`, is the first column.

```
library(RGA)

# get access token
authorize()

# get a GA profiles

ga_profiles <- list_profiles()
```

If you need (or want) that `RGA` ask for permissions every time you pull data use this code:

**Notice the `new.auth = TRUE` argument.**

```
library(RGA)

# get access token
authorize(new.auth = TRUE)

# get a GA profiles

ga_profiles <- list_profiles()
```

And to make a simple df with the data from Google Analytics:

```
id <- 88090889 #This ID is the first column from ga_profiles. Not the Account ID.

# get date when GA tracking began
first.date <- firstdate(id)


# get GA report data
ga_data <- get_ga(id, start.date = first.date, end.date = "today",
                  metrics = "ga:users,ga:sessions",
                  dimensions = "ga:userGender,ga:userAgeBracket")
```

If you need more help, post your code and we'll see.

Comment: You are awesome Omar. Thank you for taking the time to write it down so clearly!